# LaTeX table displays row numbers using scientific notation

Tags: tables, columns, line-numbering

I'm trying to make a table consisting of 4 rows and a user-specified amount of columns, where the first column contains the row number. I do this as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}



\newcommand{\myemptytable}[1]{
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/new1/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow+1}},
create on use/new2/.style={},
create on use/new3/.style={},
create on use/new4/.style={},
}
{\pgfplotstablenew[columns={new1,new2,new3,new4}]{#1}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={new1,new2,new3,new4},
string type,
columns/new1/.style={column name=Nr.},
columns/new2/.style={column name=PersonName},
columns/new3/.style={column name=Signature},
columns/new4/.style={column name=Received,column type/.add={}{|}},
before row=\hline,
every last     row/.style={after row=\hline},
column type/.add={|}{}%
]\loadedtable}
}


\begin{document}
\myemptytable{25}
\end{document}
```

This works perfectly, except that the row numbers are in scientific notation, that is, row 17 has 1.7e1 in the first column.

I've tried various ways of fixing it, but nothing helped, which is probably because I don't fully understand how `pgfplotstableset` works. Is there an easy way to turn off scientific notation throughout the document? I'm not gonna use it anyway...

Comment: Just delete the line "string type" and I think that it should work.

Answer (score 6):

Just remove your `string type` declaration.  This is overruling the standard styling for numbers (amongst other things).

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newcommand{\myemptytable}[1]{
\pgfplotstableset{
create on use/new1/.style={create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow+1}},
create on use/new2/.style={},
create on use/new3/.style={},
create on use/new4/.style={},
}
{\pgfplotstablenew[columns={new1,new2,new3,new4}]{#1}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={new1,new2,new3,new4},
columns/new1/.style={column name=Nr.},
columns/new2/.style={column name=PersonName},
columns/new3/.style={column name=Signature},
columns/new4/.style={column name=Received, column type/.add={}{|}},
before row=\hline,
every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
column type/.add={|}{}%
]\loadedtable}
}

\begin{document}
\myemptytable{25}
\end{document}
```

If the other columns actually contain strings, then you can add the `string type` to their styles.  If you really want a global `string type` declaration then it can be overridden for the first column with `numeric type`:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns={new1,new2,new3,new4},
string type,
columns/new1/.style={column name=Nr., numeric type},
columns/new2/.style={column name=PersonName},
columns/new3/.style={column name=Signature},
columns/new4/.style={column name=Received, column type/.add={}{|}},
...
```

Answer (score 5):

If it is just the table you want, you can use `tabular` and a `forloop.sty`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{PersonNumber}
\newcommand\MyEmptyTable[2][1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|r|*{3}{l|}}
    \hline
    Nr. & Person Name & Signature & Received\\\hline
    \forLoop{#1}{#2}{PersonNumber}{\thePersonNumber &&&\\\hline}
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\MyEmptyTable[5]{25}
\end{document}
```

[image]